# List of dict to dataframe not coming in order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a for loop from which i am generating a list of dict like below

```
   isv = []
   for obj in hearts:            
       rawvalue = obj.raw - readvalue
       if rawvalue < 0:
           rawvalue = rawvalue + 440
       else:
           rawvalue
       obj = str(obj)
       obj = ((obj.strip('<').split(" ")[0]))
       isv.append({'Plo':obj,'Ots': viewdata(rawvalue)[0][3],'Gts':viewdata(rawvalue)[0][0],'Mts': viewdata(rawvalue)[0][1],'Frts': viewdata(rawvalue)[0][2],'Fin':rawvalue})
```

i am creating a dataframe from this list of dict as below

```
pdadata = pd.DataFrame(isv)
```

For some reason, the DF columns are not in order as mentioned in the isv.append as  Plo,Ots,Gts,Mts,Frts,Fin 
What should be done to make this work

**Sample Data:**

```
Plo Ots     Gts     Mts     Frts    Fin
1   Parcel  Red     Blue    Yellow  678.547
2   Gift    Green   purple  Black   876.214
3   Order   Green   purple  Black   877.217
4   Base    Green   purple  Black   922.145
5   Flat    Green   purple  Black   964.2
6   Deal    Green   purple  Black   400
7   Mission Green   purple  Black   450.124
8   Base    Green   purple  Black   520.2145
9   Flat    Green   purple  Black   570.145
10  Deal    Green   purple  Black   600.178
```

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50434888/edit) your question to include some data so  we can replicate your error?

Comment: Added the sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not expect `pandas` to treat dictionaries as an *ordered* collection, even in Python 3.6+ where ordering is preserved for dictionaries internally.

If column order is important, you have a couple of options.

**Reorder after constructing your datafraome**

Simply realign column order via a list:

```
col_list = ['Plo', 'Ots', 'Gts', 'Mts', 'Frts', 'Fin']
pdadata = pdadata[col_list]
```

**Use collections.OrderedDict**

You can append `OrderedDict` objects to your list rather than regular dictionaries.

Note that this is typically implemented via a list of tuples:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

isv.append(OrderedDict([('Plo', obj), ('Ots', viewdata(rawvalue)[0][3]),
                        ('Gts', viewdata(rawvalue)[0][0]),
                        ('Mts',  viewdata(rawvalue)[0][1]),
                        ('Frts', viewdata(rawvalue)[0][2]), ('Fin', rawvalue)]))
```

Comment: i am able to make the ordereddict option work, thanks. How can i do the other one? what should i do after realigning the column order via a list

Comment: @Python_newbie, That's it, nothing else. If you `print(pdadata)`, the columns will be aligned as per the order in `col_list`.

Comment: sorry, this question may look bad, the pdadata is where i am storing the dataframe, and i should use the same variable name? i dont get it :(

Comment: It's up to you, if you want to store it in the same variable, use `pdadata = pdadata[col_list]`. There's absolutely nothing wrong with this. If you want to store it a new variable use `pdadata2 = pdadata[col_list]`. The principle is the same, to reorder columns use `df[col_list]`.